# Firedac and Oracle : works at runtime but not at design time

Tags: delphi, oracle11g, firedac

Hello to all Stackoverflow readers.

I'm trying to establish a connexion from a Delphi application to an Oracle database on my network, using FireDac.

At runtime, a "simple" :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    with FDConnection1.Params do
      begin
        DriverID := 'Ora';
        Database := '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.168.4.23)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=DBPROD)))';
        UserName := 'user';
        Password := 'password';
      end;

      FDConnection1.Open;
      FDQuery1.Open;
end;
```

works fine and the DBGrid is showing data (FDConnection disconnect not showed).

But can someone tell me why, when I try to setup and test the FDConnection at design time, I keep on getting the annoying message :

```
[FireDAC][Phys][Ora] ORA-12546: TNS:permission denied
```

The parameters I use are exactly the same, and the FDPhysOracleDriverLink is on the form with the correct oci.dll setup.

I also add that I compile in 32bits and the oci.dll is 32 bits.

Thank in advance for any advice your could provide

Have a good day

Math

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is not a problem in the authentication mode.
Select the correct option in the component TFDConnection and TFDPhysOracleDriverLink

The Oracle authentification mode:

- **Normal** -- standard user. Default value.
- **SysDBA** -- user with database administrator privileges.
- **SysOper** -- user with database operator privileges.
- **SysASM** -- user with database administrative privileges for Oracle Automatic Storage Management instances.
- **SysBackup** -- user with database administrative privileges for Backup and Recovery operations.
- **SysDG** -- user with database administrative privileges for Oracle Data Guard operations.
- **SysKM** -- user with database administrative privileges for Transparent Data Encryption keystore operations.